# airbnb/React-dates, what is the startDateId property?

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I have implemented successfully the Reac-dates range as it is explained [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates),
my concern is

**What are these props startDateId and endDateId useful for???**

```
<DateRangePicker
  startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
  startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
  endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
  onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
/>
```

I know it might be a simple answer but I haven't found an explanation, all it says is that it must be a unique string, I have put it the same string on both properties and it is still working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for accessibility, the input field should be wrapped in a `<label>` tag that is also linked to with `id` of the input. Each `id` is supposed to be unique on the page so it can't reliably be generated within the component, hence it is passed as a prop.

Comment: Cool, do you have a reference of this explanation??

Comment: A long time ago (a year or so) I read it on the Github issues list for the react-dates project. Here's a link to the comment from the project owner.  https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/326